# Can't we launch the emulator separately in Android Studio?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Launched the emulator separately to keep it resized to a small window

When deploying the project, got the Java Code 1 exception

The question: the Studio can not detect an AVD run separately? Eclipse and QtCreator both had no problems with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be an adb problem. ADB-server restart helped